# How to calculate total working hours using two time from two table -month wise in a year

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi Iam developing a attendance application, were in the web part iam in need to generate a report month wise.
the format of report is as follows:

```
**Month**    **Total Work Hour**
October              10
November             12
December             30
```

Since i'm new to sql, i tried to sum the  total work hours from table using the query:

```
SELECT   TIME_FORMAT(SUM(
TIMEDIFF (b.`checkOut_Api_DateTime`,  a.`check_In_ApiDateTime` ) ),'%H:%i:00') AS MONTH
FROM `checkinlogtable` a,`checkoutlogtable` b WHERE a.`logId`=b.`checkIn_log_id` AND YEAR(a.`check_In_ApiDateTime`)=2015
```

[My Check In Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqrh3.jpg)

[My CheckOut Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhdh6.jpg)

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before finding the sum of time differences for each employee, you have to convert time difference into hours and then calculate total hours(you are missing this part in the above query). Mysql provides a function TIME_TO_SEC() to convert provided argument into seconds.
Have a look at mysql [datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html.) functions for more information.

Below is the query.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(b.`checkOut_Api_DateTime`, a.`check_In_ApiDateTime` ))/3600),'%H:%i:00') AS MONTH
FROM `checkinlogtable` a,`checkoutlogtable` b 
WHERE a.`logId`=b.`checkIn_log_id` AND YEAR(a.`check_In_ApiDateTime`)=2015 and a.employeeId='R374'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped